# Use SCRUM for website maintenance - Deal with single task

Tags: agile, scrum, sprint

I am new to Scrum and I am trying to use it for website support and maintenance.

For website support and maintenance, we often receive small tasks, for example: replace a banner on homepage, change phone number on contact page, remove image xyz on article 123, etc... I don't know how to deal with these small tasks in Scrum.

At the moment, I create a single task in backlog, and a single Sprint for each task. Then, execute each task individually. Am I right?

Comment: better use Kanban - it perfectly matches maintenance activity

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: Thank you @skyboyer. Kanban is exactly what we need.

Answer (score 3):

In Scrum we have fixed length, repeating [sprints](https://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#events-sprint). *We bring work to the sprint*, rather than creating sprints from tasks.

This is useful for a number of reasons, including:

- After a while we get to know the *capacity* of a sprint.
- We know at the start of the sprint what we will be doing and there is no change to the sprint goal during the sprint. This stability helps the team get organised.
- The regular cadence helps the team get into a rhythm of planning, executing and then adapting.

Scrum isn't as effective if:

- You don't have a team of 3-9 people
- Work items and priorities change frequently and stable sprints are not possible

From your description, I wonder if Scrum is the best agile framework for your team.

Perhaps you might consider using [Kanban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanban_(development))?

Comment: @TyTrinh If you like the answer and think it best answers your question, you could select it as the chosen answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.  This helps people find answers that were deemed as correct by the asker, and also awards the answerer points for the correct answer.